# How to get all the columns in model.matrix

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, model.matrix

Suppose we have a data.frame :

```
> df <- data.frame(A = c('a','a','b','c','c','b','a'), B = c('d','e','e','e','f','f','g'))
```

On printing the values we'll get:

```
> df
  A B
1 a d
2 a e
3 b e
4 c e
5 c f
6 b f
7 a g
```

On applying `model.matrix` , it gives:

```
> d <- model.matrix(~.,df)
> d
  (Intercept) Ab Ac Be Bf Bg
1           1  0  0  0  0  0
2           1  0  0  1  0  0
3           1  1  0  1  0  0
4           1  0  1  1  0  0
5           1  0  1  0  1  0
6           1  1  0  0  1  0
7           1  0  0  0  0  1
```

Now, as we could see in the factor `df$A`, there are **3** unique characters *i.e ( a, b, c)*. But, in its equivalent *model.matrix* we have `Ab`, `Ac`. Similarly, in case of `df$B`, `Bd` is missing.

So, My question is how can we get **all** the columns in a `model.matrix` representation, *if i'm neglecting the `Intercept`* ?

Comment: Unless you explicitly specify you don't want one, `model.matrix`
 specifies an intercept by default. One level of each factor is represented by the intercept. They can't be there again or the system would be over-determined.

Comment: But, if i want to introduce all the parameters and not the `Intercept`, then would i do that. I mean is there any direct way to do that.

Comment: You can suppress the intercept (see `help("formula")`). However, you would still not get all factor levels because the system would still be over-determined if they were there.

Comment: Are you just looking for `model.matrix(~. - 1, df)`? Or the equivalent `model.matrix( ~. + 0 , df)`?

Comment: See, I have tried both ways but still not got what i'm looking for. I expect all the columns ,means all the factors along with their levels. Here we could have said `Aa`, `Ab`, `Ac`, `Bd`, `Be`, `Bf`, `Bg`.

Comment: These two functions give you exactly that. Have you tried it?